# Why are CiviCRM fields not displaying from a view in a panel in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-views

I feel like I am missing something fairly basic, but here goes.

I am trying to display CiviCRM Contact fields from a view that will be displayed in a content pane of a panel, but they just don't appear.

My view has a mix of Drupal and CiviCRM fields.  The Drupal fields appear in the panel, but the CiviCRM fields don't.  When I display the view as a standalone page, the CiviCRM fields appear along with the Drupal fields.

It would seem, then, that the problem is passing the CiviCRM data to the panel.

Is there a context or relationship that is required in the panel?

I have added CiviCRM fields directly from the 'CiviCRM Contact' tab of the 'add content' wizard in Panels, but they exhibit the same behaviour.  The fields don't appear on the front end of the site (or in previews).

I am working with Drupal 7.50 and CiviCRM 4.7.6.

Thanks for your help,
Lewis

Comment: Are the Drupal fields connected to the Civi fields that should be shown? If so, you might need to add a filter rule connecting the two.

Comment: What is a 'filter' rule and at what stage would I add it? In the Panel? Do you mean a Context in the Panel? Which type will work? I have tried several with no success. Do you mean a Relationship within the Panel? Sorry.  Just not sure which feature you're referring to and how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. To answer your question, 'yes'.  These are Drupal User fields and linked CiviCRM Contact fields, e.g. Drupal username and CiviCRM First Name and Last Name.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I meant to refer to the option for "contextual filters" in views. Let me see if I can get some screenshots...

Comment: Oh I see now, you're really having more of a panels issue than a views one, since it's working in views. Hm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was not specific to CiviCRM fields.  The issue is in the relationship between Views and Panels, specifically, passing arguments between the two.

The missing piece for us was using the 'Argument input' setting in Views to pass the arguments properly.

Eventually discovered a great post about it here:
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/passing-page-arguments-view-panes

I won't try to reproduce it.  Following these steps solved our problem.

Enjoy,
Lewis